# Log4j2 JDBC Appender with JNDI datasource on IBM Web Sphere giving error no connection available

Tags: jdbc, websphere, log4j2, jndi

I am trying to use Log4J2 JDBC appender to insert log records to Oracle database. My spring boot application EAR is deployed to IBM Web Sphere. I am using JNDI data resource defined in Web Sphere.  My log4j2 XML configuration is

```
<JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="tphms_dba.WAS_APP_LOG">                    <DataSource jndiName="jdbc/APPLOGDS" />                 
<Column name="LOG_DATE" isEventTimestamp="true" />      
<Column name="LOG_LEVEL" pattern="%level" />
 </JDBC>
```

The error that I am getting is

org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Cannot write logging event; JDBC manager not connected to the database

[06/04/23 16:57:03:753 EDT] 00000057 SystemOut     O 2023-04-06 16:57:03,752 server.startup : 1 ERROR Unable to write to database [JdbcManager{name=databaseAppender, bufferSize=0, tableName=WAS_APP_LOG, columnConfigs=[{ name=LOG_DATE, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=LOG_LEVEL, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[]}] for appender [databaseAppender]. org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Cannot write logging event; JDBC manager not connected to the database, running=true, [columnConfigs=[{ name=LOG_DATE, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=LOG_LEVEL, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }], sqlStatement=insert into tphms_dba.WAS_APP_LOG (LOG_DATE,LOG_LEVEL) values (?,?), factoryData=FactoryData [connectionSource=dataSource{ name=jdbc/APPLOGDS, value=com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcDataSource@58f6b427 }, tableName=WAS_APP_LOG, columnConfigs=[{ name=LOG_DATE, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=LOG_LEVEL, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[], immediateFail=false, retry=true, reconnectIntervalMillis=5000, truncateStrings=true], connection=null, statement=null, reconnector=Reconnector [latch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@baa822a2[Count = 0], shutdown=false], isBatchSupported=true, columnMetaData=null])

Comment: Your configuration does not contain a JDBC source configuration: cf. [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender) for examples.

Comment: I have following in the config <DataSource jndiName="jdbc/APPLOGDS" />

Comment: Can you update the configuration in your question? The `<DataSource>` element must be inside the `<JDBC>` element.